# X argument in train_test_split is whole data without target class or it also contain target class?

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=42)
```

(1) y argument is target class. what is X? X is whole dataset having target class attribute as well or without target class attribute.

(2)And how can we get X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, if we have separate files (train.csv, test.csv) of training and testing data.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to use `train_test_split` if you already have a train/test split done? (Thats's for your question 2)

Comment: I need both methods for 2 different purposes, For one dataset i don't have splitted data, and for another dataset have splitted data.

Comment: That probably should be added to the question. Just read the data in from the files separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone new in ML there is always strange that the name "test" is used in two different meanings, the first one as "valid", the second as the "real" test.
`train_test_split` splits original train (X) into a reduced train (X_train) and valid (X_test), and the target exists in both parts if you do not remove it before splitting.
Talking about the files train.csv and test.csv we are talking about a train with the target and a "real" test without the target - `train_test_split` has nothing to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import data from single file only. Module train_test_split will split the data. So here all data is inside "Salary_Data.csv".

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 0)
```

Comment: So you are saying that we are not supposed to add target class in attribute X

Comment: @IrfanUmar may i know what do you mean by target class?

Comment: Target class is attribute about which we want to predict

Comment: @IrfanUmar that column is already there. When you train the data it uses this target class and when you test it , it matches with the existing target class in test data set to check for the accuracy.

Comment: `dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
X = dataset .drop(['HasDetections'], axis=1)
Y = dataset ['HasDetections']` So, is it right to do so? where HasDetections is target class.

Comment: @IrfanUmar thats what these two lines are doing X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values.  So, your understanding is totally correct only check the code if it is correct.

Comment: @IrfanUmar if you want i can post full code. thumbs up.

Comment: No, I don't need it. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 0):

> (1) y argument is target class. what is X? X is whole dataset having
>   target class attribute as well or without target class attribute.

X are the features in your machine learning problem, so it is without the target value y.

With cvs.files you will have several columns:

```
Sepal_length Sepal_width  class
0             1           0
1             1           1
```

Then X would be: `X=df[['Sepal_length', 'Sepal_width']]` and `y=df[['class']]`

> 2)And how can we get X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, if we have separate files (train.csv, test.csv) of training and testing data.

You already have to files: Train and Test, so no need to split it. But there is a possibility of a validation set.

The approach is:

**Train set**: Train your algorithm, and change the parameters of your ML

**Validation set:** Test your algorithm and validate the parameters, note that you don't use this for training

**Test set:** Save your ML and use it for the test set, also this data is completly unseen.

In your case: `train.csv`is your train set and validation set
and `test.csv`probably your test set (it could also be validation and test set with a split)